# The integral of $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt {x}-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, radicals

Can anyone help me with this? I have been racking my brain for days trying to solve this. I tried splitting the equation into two integrals and multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ for the differential but nothing works. The only hint the book gives me is that $u = \sqrt{x} - 1$.

Thanks for checking.
-Lester

Comment: There's a thing here called Mathjax... I suggest you use it. Here's a good tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Write $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\sqrt{x}+1+\frac2{\sqrt x-1}$$ and integrate.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Simplifire, I really appreciate you helping me with this. I admit that I do feel a little stupid that I didn't break it down better more comprehensively than I did. How do you suppose that solution is typically derived? Is it just realizing that the numerator looks close to the difference of two squares and going from there? I found this problem in the book TAN Applied Calculus; it is finally starting to test my algebra comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

If you make the change of variable
$$
u=\sqrt{x}-1,\quad x=(u+1)^2, \quad dx=2(u+1)du,
$$ then you get an easy rational function to integrate
$$
\int\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}-1}\:dx=2\int\frac{(u+1)^3+(u+1)}{u}\:du.
$$

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is $x = t^2$ so that $dx = 2t \, dt$

$$\int\frac{2t(t^2+1)}{t-1} dt = \int 2t(t+1) dt +\int 4 dt+\int\frac{4}{t-1} dt$$

I hope you can handle this easily :)

Comment: @lester never mind !! ☺️

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}-1}dx=\int\frac{x\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)}dx=\int\frac{x\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}-2+2}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)}dx=$$
$$=\int\frac{x\sqrt{x}-x+x-\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{x}-2}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)}dx+\int\frac{4}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)}dx=$$
$$=\int\frac{x+\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{x}}dx+4\ln|\sqrt{x}-1|=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^3}+x+4\sqrt{x}+4\ln|\sqrt{x}-1|+C.$$

Comment: Thank y'all. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome!